# Seemingly unable to work with ints in struct

Tags: c++, struct, int, arguments, scalar

```
struct stVitals                       // Entity vitals
{
    int str;
    int xp;
    int batk;
};

int doAttack(stVitals Aggressor, stVitals Defender)    // Calculate attack results
{
    doHit(getATK(Aggressor), getDEF(Defender), getDDG(Defender), getLVL(Aggressor), getLVL(Defender));
}

int doHit([...]                       // Calculate damage

int getATK(stVitals sourcemob)        // Calculate attack value
{
    int output = ((sourcemob.str * getLVL(sourcemob.xp)) * 0.1) + sourcemob.batk;
    return output;
}

int getLVL(int xp)                    // Return level from XP
{
    return (xp * 0.001);
}
```

Gives the following error:

```
ERROR: Conversion from 'int' to non-scalar type 'stVitals' requested
```

I work with ints within various stVital instances all around my program in this manner with no problems... what's going on here that I'm missing?

edit: It is hollering about the first line inside of getATK

Comment: Can you post the exact line that corresponds to the error.  The code you posted looks OK (except for the double `0.1` multiplying an integer value then being converted -- implicitly? -- back to an `int`).

Comment: I bet that you forgot to do a member access operator to get one of your struct's member variables; oh, and your compiler should holler about the line number.........

Comment: edit: It is hollering about the first line inside of getATK (the int/double stuff is fine, as it produces the particular range of numbers i'm looking for in isolation)

Comment: The only reason it should be complaining about that line is if your `getATK` (or `getLVL`) isn't the same as posted here.

Comment: It's obviously **not** 100% verbatim, because the `doHit` definition is nonsense.

Comment: `getLVL` is being passed an `stVitals` but expects an `int`.

Comment: Check again.  You're calling `getLVL` two different (and inconsistent) ways here...in `doAttack` you're passing it an `stVitals`, and in `getATK` you're passing an int.  One or the other is wrong.  And if it's complaining about the line in `getATK`, that'd mean `getLVL` is expecting an `stVitals`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's missing here is the code in which you call `getATK`. Presumably, you're incorrectly passing an `int` argument rather than an `stVitals` argument when you call that function.

Comment: You call to getLVL is receiving the stVitals object `Aggressor`, but it expects an `int`.

Comment: Oh hell. Thanks! - it's always the littlest stuff that's hardest to spot... I left off the ".xp"

Answer (score 0):

getLvl is being called with a stVitals by doAttack();